# Divergence of reciprocal of primes, Euler

Tags: sequences-and-series, distribution-of-primes

On Wikipedia at [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) currently is:

\begin{align}
 \ln \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\right) & {} = \ln\left( \prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-1}}\right)
  = -\sum_p \ln \left( 1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \\
 & {} = \sum_p \left( \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{2p^2} + \frac{1}{3p^3} + \cdots \right) \\
 & {} = \sum_{p}\frac{1}{p}+  \sum_{p}\frac{1}{2p^2} +  \sum_{p}\frac{1}{3p
^3} +  \sum_{p}\frac{1}{4p^4} + \cdots  \\
 & {} = \left( \sum_p \frac{1}{p} \right) + K
\end{align}

And then Wikipedia says that $K<1$, without any explanation. How do we know that $$\sum_{p}\frac{1}{2p^2} +  \sum_{p}\frac{1}{3p
^3} +  \sum_{p}\frac{1}{4p^4} + \cdots$$ is equal to a constant $K<1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in fact do better and show that $K < 0.43$.

$$
\sum_{p}\frac{1}{2p^2} +  \sum_{p}\frac{1}{3p
^3} +  \sum_{p}\frac{1}{4p^4} + \cdots = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p}\frac{1}{np^n} 
$$

$$
<  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{nk^n} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(n) - 1}{n} = 1 - \gamma \approx 0.422785
$$

where Gamma is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: You meant $\sum_{n=2}^\infty$. And we can use $\zeta(n)-1 \le 2^{-n}+\int_2^\infty x^{-n}dx$

Comment: Yes its n = 2 to infinity. The summation involving the zeta function can be computed directly by flipping the order of summation i.e. first summing over n as the inner sum and then summing this result over k to get $1-  \gamma$

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$$\sum_p \frac {1}{p^s} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{n^s} = \zeta(s) $$

$\zeta(s)$ is Riemann Zeta function, and $\zeta(s)$ converges for each $s \in \Bbb R, s>1$